# Mad npm on windows 8 - tries to install weird packages in endless loop

Tags: windows-8, npm

When I try to install whatever package using npm (node. 0.10.21 x64), npm downloads desired package (entries in node_modules exists but package is not functional) but it continues to download weird packages (not dependencies) and it seems that it gets stuck in some kind of endless loop. **Below npm-debug.log from express install**, but I cancelled it after a couple of minutes.

[link to npm-debug.log (very long)](http://pastebin.com/SfVnZEKu)

Comment: So, what command line have you used..?

Comment: Just what I wrote, npm install express